# Stop HDFS Balancer after using nohup

Tags: hdfs, nohup

I've launched my HDFS balancer with the nohup command :

```
$ nohup hdfs balancer &
```

It is taking forever and I need to work on my cluster. Do you know how can I stop the process ?

It's a distributed process so it's quite difficult to stop by juste doing  "kill PID" ...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the HDFS balancer is *not* a distributed process. It is a single process that initiates block movements on the cluster; the balancing process is carried out in a distributed manner cooperatively by DataNodes, but the commands about which blocks to balance originate from a single process (the one created by `hdfs balancer`). Doing a `kill $PID` will be sufficient to stop any further balancing.

Source: [HDFS Balancer documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Balancer), personal experience.

Comment: i killed the balancer process, then run again, but get error: java.io.IOException: Another Balancer is running..  Exiting ...

Comment: @Furyegg The balancer process creates a file named `/system/balancer.id` to indicate that it is running. Other balancer processes will check if this file exists and if the lease on the file has expired. If you wait for the hard lease expiration period (1 hr), or manually delete the file `/system/balancer.id`, you should be able to successfully start a new balancer.